# AS3 framerate change issue

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a KeyboardEvent that switches Boolean, if true an FR var drops -2/frame to a bottom of 10, if false it rises +2/frame to a top of 60. It works fine going up and down but whenever I add "stage.frameRate = FR;" to an ENTER_FRAME function and play it, it freezes the control over the window. Animation still plays but I can't turn it off unless via Ctrl-Alt-Del.

1.Why is this happening?

2.Is it possible to change frameRate every frame?

3.If yes, how?

Comment: Do you have the animation on the timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, I am not sure playing with the frame rate on the fly is a good thing to be doing. What are you trying to do? Perhaps there is a better way...

This is a total guess, but perhaps when you set the frame rate to the stage it initialises 'something' in the background. Then since you have it happening every frame, it'll try to initialises on every frame, causing it to be locked up.

---

Updating answer to include an example of using a Timer object:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

// the timer takes in milliseconds, so for 30 frames/second, you would have a frame tick at every 1000 / 30, or 33.333ms
var tickSpeed:int = 1000 / 30;
var frameTick:Timer = new Timer(tickSpeed, 0);


function enterFrameListener(inputEvent:Timer):void {
    // this method will run on every timer tick
}
frameTick.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, enterFrameListener);

// can change the tick speed of the timer like so (setting it to 1000 means 1 frame tick every second)
frameTick.delay = 1000;

// according to the api doc however, a tickspeed of less then 20ms is not recommended
// 20ms would be equal to 60 fps
```

By offloading it to a timer, you shouldn't need to mess around with the overall framerate with another advantage of other objects can be affected by different timers at the same time. Timer class also has a few helpful methods in itself as well: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: I thought about slow-motion. One way is to take all the code in the stage and change values one by one. Another one is to base all the values on variables that will be changed all at once. But if I need a smooth transition, it will still take huge addition to the code. And changing frameRate seemed like a good way to me: set a higher rate, 60, and make 6x difference to a high enough rate for seemingly smooth animation. This way I'd get all the "world" slowing or speeding and would only have to adjust the controllable symbol speed. Any ideas? ^_^'

Comment: And it's pretty simple for now, just a value I change and display in a text field. I make sure it's not "over 9000" to slow PC down. First I made it work, then I added 1 line above. Which made it freeze but not the animation of moving objects. They seem to still go at 60 fps speed. I saw an example in the net where animation changed it's speed as you press a button changing frameRate as it goes. They used 1 line either... Button press -> frameRate += 1

Comment: Hm, is all your animation based on frame/ENTER_FRAME events? If so, maybe you can change it to fire on a timer then and control the speed of that. I'll update my answer to include an example of this.

Comment: +1 for suggesting use of timer instead of solution with frame rates.

Comment: You genius! Thanks! =D Must be silly of me to not think about non-direct frame rate. Well, something new learned today ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is freezing because you are trying to set the frame rate on every frame, i would suggest you should check your frame rate in your `ENTER_FRAME` section. if your frame rate goes up/down from you desired frame rate, then you should set your frame rate to FR.

Try this can help you.